# Is there any way to save Data as Small as Possible in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web application using PHP and MySQL. I want to know that is there any way to save Data as Small as Possible in MySQL?

Comment: Do you want to save space on the harddisk? Will you have insane amounts of dates stored? Will you index by that date? What precision do you need? Days, seconds, minutes, nanoseconds? Smallest / largest date you want to store?

Comment: Small means in size or length ?

Comment: @biziclop No i just want small Data file

Comment: possible duplicate of [compress text before storing in mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782565/compress-text-before-storing-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the lengths of date types in MySQL, choose whichever fits your needs. You can save 1 more byte by defining the column as `NOT NULL`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html says:

```
Storage Requirements for Date and Time Types
Data Type   Storage Required
DATE        3 bytes
TIME        3 bytes
DATETIME    8 bytes
TIMESTAMP   4 bytes
YEAR        1 byte
```

If your MySQL engine is up-to-date enough, you might want to check out InnoDB's row compression (which might make database operations slower though):

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html

Answer (score 1):

If it's space savings you're after try looking at the "ARCHIVE" engine for mysql.  It does have some restrictions in so far as you can only have 1 index on the table and you cant "update" data once it's there but it is very fast and useful for (as the name suggests) archiving data.

There may be other ways to save space too - like compressing data in the fields themselves but this will need care especially if you intend to search on these compressed fields.